# What is the best way to refactor out “temporal dependence” of instance methods?

Tags: javascript

For example, suppose in a view class we need to instantiate some UI components and then populate the fields. Something like:

```
var View = function() {
  this._initUI();
  this._populateFields();
};

View.prototype = {
  _initUI: function() {
    this.textField = new TextField();
    this.comboBox = new Combobox();
  },

  _populateFields: function() {
    this.textField.setText('foo');
    this.comboBox.setVal('bar');
  }
};
```

This doesn't quite smell right, as you must call `_initUI` before `_populateFields`, and it's pretty hidden that `_initUI` will be creating some instance variables that will later be used by `_populateFields`.

What's your opinion of a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You could have a flag that is set when `_initUI` is called.  The first line of `_initUI` would check the flag and exit if it's already set; the second line would set it.  Then any method which needs `_initUI` to have been called can simply, safely, call it without fear of double-initializing things.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure it is something to be worried about, if you really want to address this and if your `_initUI` is really that short you could inline the `_initUI` function:

```
var View = function() {
  this.textField = new TextField();
  this.comboBox  = new Combobox();
  this._populateFields();
};

View.prototype = {
  _populateFields: function() {
    this.textField.setText('foo');
    this.comboBox.setVal('bar');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're saying is `_populateFields` is *dependent* on `_initUI`.  You could model this dependency in a few ways.  You could call `_initUI` from `_populateFields`:

```
_populateFields: function() {
    _initUI();
    ...etcetera...
}
```

If you have a library that defines `assert` in Javascript you could add a flag and an assert:

```
_initUI: function() {
    initialized = true;
    ...etcetera...
}
_populateFields: function() {
    assert(initialized);
    ...etcetera...
}
```

This gives you the advantage of being able to call `_populateFields` multiple times without calling `_initUI` again, as well as letting you separate the calls in time.

You could combine the two, calling `_initUI` conditionally at the start of `_populateFields` if it hasn't been called yet.

```
_initUI: function() {
    initialized = true;
    ...etc...
}

_populateFields: function() {
    if (!initialized) {
        _initUI();
    }
    ...etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can assure that the view should be initialized on construction time, why not use the constructor or return a already initialized object?

```
var View = function() {
    var textField = new TextField(),
        comboBox = new Combobox();

    return {
        populateFields: function () {
            textField.setText('foo');
            comboBox.setVal('bar');
        }
    };
};
```

This eliminates all flags to check if the view is initialized and hides the initialization so noone can call it (as I assume it is private).

If you can't assure that it's ok to initialize the view on construction time, an internal flag is probably the easy way to go. Yet I'd go with the assertion way. Calling `populateField` on an un-initialized view indicates a bug/flaw in your application logic. This is not the right scenario for lazy initialization.